# How to get first 3 characters from ACF date picker month?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, laravel-blade

I'm trying to format the date I get returned from the ACF date picker field. Currently it returns the date as ('F d, y') and is shown as October 16, 2018. However I would like it to be shown as Oct 16, 2018.

Basicly strip the month string to only show the first 3 characters. Any ideas?

**View:**

```
@if(!empty($posts))
    @include('layouts.posts', $posts)
@else
  <p>No Events to show</p>
@endif
```

**layouts.posts:**

```
<div class="post-items">
    @if ( count($posts) > 0)
      @foreach ($posts as $key => $post)
        <div class="post-item" >
            @if ($post['date'] != '')
                <div class="post-item__date">
                    {!! $post['date'] !!}
                </div>
            @endif
            {!! $post['content']!!}
      </div><!-- .post-item -->
      @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function posts() {
$posts = [];

foreach ($this->wp_query->posts as $key => $post) {

    $posts[$key]['date'] = get_field('acf__event_date', $post->ID);
    $posts[$key]['content'] =
                '
            <h2>'.$post->post_title.'</h2>
            <p>'.wp_trim_words(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID), 30).'</p>
            <p><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" class="button">Read more</a></p>';
}

return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey After getting the field with

```
$date = get_field('date', false, false);
```

you can create a new **php DateTime** object from that date

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
```

and then use the native php format function

```
$date->format('M j, Y');
```

the **M** option gives you automatically the month initials

Comment: After doing this I get the following error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
Edit: solved it, see above

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by letting ACF give me a custom format back with ('M j, Y').

Comment: Glad to know you explored the options available in the plugin itself :)